# Match from Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a leave tracker workbook with 14 sheets that are used to plot employee leave.

[Leave tracker sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbx07.png)

As you can see from the picture below, I have code that works to check 'October' but I can't figure out how to check all of the other months. I would like to be able to write any date in AP14 and it will tell me who is booked to be off on that date.

I would also like it to tell me what kind of leave it is (H,E,A,S,U).

[Search Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR9GS.png)

The code I am currently using is.... (in the stated cells)

```
AR14=MATCH(AP14,October!$4:$4,0)    
AM16= IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(October!$7:$33)/(INDEX(October!$7:$34,0,$AS$14)
<>""),ROWS(AM$16:AM16)),"") 
AN16=IFERROR(INDEX(October!$1:$1048576,$AM16,2),"") 
AO16=IFERROR(INDEX(October!$1:$1048576,$AM16,3),"") 
AP16=IFERROR(INDEX(October!$1:$1048576,$AM16,4),"") 
AQ16=IFERROR(INDEX(October!$1:$1048576,$AM16,5),"")
```

How can I include the index and/or Match to other sheets?

Comment: Google: VLOOKUP, INDEX

Comment: _Welcome to Stack Overflow!_  It's a good idea to check out the [tour] and [ask]...  'i have code that works to check 'October' but i cant figure out how to check all of the other months'  Does that mean you can figure out October?  It shouldn't be much more than copy & pasting formulas between the months.   @Worthy7's suggestions is a good place to start

Comment: [Here is an example](https://exceljet.net/formula/lookup-with-variable-sheet-name) of VLOOKUP with INDIRECT for looking across sheets with month names.  Hope that helps get you started.